# UCWords not converting string to uppercase for each word

Tags: php

Using the PHP manual on [ucwords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) here I converted my PHP echo.

```
echo(ucwords($row['Subdivision']));
```

The results is still in all upper case like this:

WHISPER LAKE

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php follow this page

Comment: cool save my day.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
echo ucwords(strtolower($row['Subdivision']));
```

In case of all latter are in upper `ucwords` does no change the case. so you need to convert the string in lower case first.

You can see the example in the link which is given by you. [The link is here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php).

You whole word is in upper case that's why is not working.

`ucwords` function is used to convert the first letter of each words in upper case of string. And if it is in upper case already then will remain same. It will not work for other letter of word to covert it in lower case.

Comment: Well, that's silly! (I guess technically the description on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) doesn't *technically* say it changes any letters besides the first of each word...but jeesh!)  Thanks+

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who encounters this currently.  The solution is:

echo ucfirst(strtolower($row['Subdivision']));

Comment: This will not work on the OP's supplied sample string `WHISPER LAKE`.